# Collect File Permissions, Export to CSV, Export "Access Denied" File Path

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I was working on gathering data about network drive permissions, I have been able to get the data I want but I would like to be able to error handle better, especially for "access denied" where I don't have permissions to view the folder permissions.

```
$PathtoScan = "\\folderxxx\folderyyy"

$GetFileInfo=Get-ChildItem "$PathtoScan" -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop | 
Where {$_.Mode -match "d"} | 
Get-NTFSAccess | Select-Object Name,FullName,InheritanceEnabled,IsInherited, 
InheritedFrom, AccessRights, Account |
Export-Csv C:\Scripts\dump.csv -NoTypeInformation

try {

$GetFileInfo

} 
catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException] {Write-Host "Message: 
[$($_.Exception.Message)" | Out-File C:\Scripts\test.txt ]

}
```

The error message that I trying to catch:

```
Get-NTFSAccess : (5) Access is denied: [\\folderxxx\folderyyy]
At C:\Scripts\ACL.ps1:4 char:1
+ Get-NTFSAccess | Select-Object Name,FullName,InheritanceEnabled,IsInh ...

+ CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (\\folderxxx\folderyyy) [Get-NTFSAccess], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReadSecurityError,NTFSSecurity.GetAccess
```

Ideally I would like to export the path to where I dont have access to view the permissions to remediate.

I used: `$Error[0].exception |  Get-Member` to get a better sense of the error it appears I am trying to catch: `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a number of bugs here.

First, you're doing this:

```
$GetFileInfo = Get-ChildItem [...] |
[...] |
Export-Csv C:\Scripts\dump.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

`Export-Csv` doesn't return any objects to standard output at all.  You can override some cmdlets that do this with the `-PassThru` parameter, but `Export-Csv` doesn't support that parameter.  `$GetFileInfo` is *always* going to be `$null`.  Your script structure makes me think you're not understanding how the pipeline and output works.  When you write something like:

```
$x = Get-Item -Path C:\
```

You're not writing commands to be executed later when you call `$x`.  The commands are executed *immediately* and *the standard output of those commands* is assigned to the variable `$x`.

You appear to make the same mistake later in the catch block:

```
Write-Host "Message: [$($_.Exception.Message)" | Out-File C:\Scripts\test.txt ]
```

I can't tell what this is trying to do, but I guarantee that it won't do what you think it does.  Again, both `Write-Host` and `Out-File` don't send output to standard out, and neither cmdlet supports `-PassThru`.  Look:

```
PS C:\> Write-Host Hello World | Out-File C:\test.txt
Hello World
PS C:\> Get-Content C:\test.txt
PS C:\>
```

All I did was print "Hello World" and create an empty file at `C:\test.txt`.  `Write-Host` is very deceptive because it looks like it's writing to standard output, but it doesn't.  It writes directly to the console.  This is the reason you often see people say, "You probably want `Write-Output` instead of `Write-Host`," because `Write-Output` does write to standard out.  However, it's not really necessary.  You can often just not use a cmdlet for output at all.

I'm guessing you want this:

```
"Message: [$($_.Exception.Message)]" | Out-File C:\Scripts\test.txt -Append
```

Next, you're also doing this to filter directories:

```
$GetFileInfo = Get-ChildItem "$PathtoScan" -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop | 
Where {$_.Mode -match "d"} |
```

You don't ever want to use the `Mode` property.  It's *extremely* slow.  In fact, `Mode` is the reason that `Get-ChildItem` is slow with it's default output.  If you want only directories, do this:

```
$GetFileInfo = Get-ChildItem "$PathtoScan" -Recurse -Directory -ErrorAction Stop |
Get-NTFSAccess | [...]
```

Or, in PowerShell v2 and earlier:

```
$GetFileInfo = Get-ChildItem "$PathtoScan" -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop |
Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
Get-NTFSAccess | [...]
```

---

So, the above gets us closer:

```
$PathtoScan = "\\folderxxx\folderyyy"

try {
    Get-ChildItem "$PathtoScan" -Recurse -Directory -ErrorAction Stop | 
    Get-NTFSAccess | Select-Object Name,FullName,InheritanceEnabled,IsInherited, 
    InheritedFrom, AccessRights, Account |
    Export-Csv C:\Scripts\dump.csv -NoTypeInformation
} 
catch {
    "Message: [$($_.Exception.Message)" | Out-File C:\Scripts\test.txt ]
}
```

However, this is still going to stop executing completely at the first error that `Get-ChildItem` throws.  Again, that's probably not really what you want.  I'm guessing you want something closer to this:

```
$PathtoScan = "\\folderxxx\folderyyy"

# Clear the automatic error variable
$Error.Clear()

# Run the commands, but don't stop for any errors encountered and export the results to file
Get-ChildItem "$PathtoScan" -Recurse -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Get-NTFSAccess | Select-Object Name,FullName,InheritanceEnabled,IsInherited, 
InheritedFrom, AccessRights, Account |
Export-Csv C:\Scripts\dump.csv -NoTypeInformation

# If there were errors
if ($Error) {
    # Reverse the $Error ArrayList variable to put the oldest events first
    $Error.Reverse()

    # Write all the errors from the automatic error variable to file
    $Error | ForEach-Object {
        "Message: [$($_.Exception.Message)]"
    } | Out-File C:\Scripts\test.txt # You might want an -Append here
}
```

Comment: Wow! thank you, that's a much better approach. Reading up more on the try, catch. It appears that it's better for terminating errors and not what I am trying to do. Thanks from a noob, tearing it apart helps the learning process and shows what  I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to catch an error AFTER it has already happened.  Wrap your initial assignment of `$GetFileInfo` in the `Try{}` block.  In your example, I'm not even sure why you're assigning that stream of commands to a variable in the first place.  If you're trying to suppress output, you should do `$Null=`

To know exactly which error is getting thrown to utilize `Catch [Errortype]`, put

```
Catch { Write-Output "[$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)] $($_.Exception.Message)" }
```

in your block.  I'd also suggest using `$ErrorActionPreference='Stop'` at the beginning.

Comment: I went ahead and added  $ErrorActionPreference='stop' and removed the variables and put the powershell block in the try statement. Catch has: catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException] { Write-Output "[$($_.Exception.Message)]" | out-file C:\Scripts\errors.txt }. When running the script it will export one error message and stop. Is there a way for it to continue to run, logging each error as the script continues? I tried silently continue and the top and it appears to not log the errors. Thanks!